# How to assign mysql value to a single variable in vb.net?

Tags: mysql, vb.net

The following is my code for forgot password,
I want to store the value of mysql query in a variable so that i can use the variable value for placing it in a email.

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) 
Handles Button3.Click

        Dim p_text As String
        p_text = TextBox1.Text
        MsgBox(p_text)
        Dim i As Integer
        Try

            Dim conn As MySqlConnection
            conn = New MySqlConnection
            conn.ConnectionString ="server=192.168.1.111;userid=betterhomes;
            password=123456;database=betterhomes"

            conn.Open()
            Dim password As String = ""
            Dim sqlquery2 As String = "SELECT bh_password FROM bh_login 
            where job_id = '" & p_text & "';"

            Dim data2 As MySqlDataReader
            Dim adapter2 As New MySqlDataAdapter
            Dim command2 As New MySqlCommand
            command2.CommandText = sqlquery2
            command2.Connection = conn
            adapter2.SelectCommand = command2
            data2 = command2.ExecuteReader

            While data2.HasRows
                password = data2.GetString("bh_password")
                MsgBox(password)
                data2.Close()
            End While

        Catch exError As MySqlException
            '  MsgBox("Error connecting to database! Try again later")
        End Try

    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Like this

```
 If data2.Read
    password = data2.GetString("bh_password")
    MsgBox(password)
 End if
 data2.Close()
```

**Send Email**

```
Dim mail As New MailMessage()

'set the addresses
mail.From = New MailAddress("xx@xx")
mail.[To].Add("xx@xx")

' //set the content
mail.Subject = "This is an email"
mail.Body = password 

' // set the server
Dim smtp As New SmtpClient("localhost")

' // send the message
Try
    smtp.Send(mail)
    Response.Write("Your Email has been sent sucessfully - Thank You")
Catch exc As Exception
    Response.Write("Send failure: " & exc.ToString())
End Try
```

Comment: Please provide some explanation how this solves the problem. That will enable future visitors to understand the problem and your solution. Thank You

Comment: Well i wanted to send the password to the email id and i was not getting the output of the mysql query stored in the variable "password" but now that problem is solved as msgbox(password) gives the password as output

Comment: @user3787753 Now Check it do you want this?